# Google Map with Layout layer above it

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-2

I am adding a layout above Google Map with my own layout having transparent Background. Now when I add it I am not able to move the Google Map inside my app as there is a Frame layout above it. My requirement is that I want my Google Map to work like swipe zoom and everything even when I have a Framelayout above it.

Below is the sample code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".ui.googlemapactivity.GoogleMapMainActivity" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frameTop"
        android:layout_above="@+id/llBottomButtom"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/llBottomButtom"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="90">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnOne"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Route" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnTwo"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Current" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnThree"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Charge" />


    </LinearLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Support Map Fragment here does not swipe move or anything. Any solution for the same?

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

the problem is you are trying to add `android:layout_above="@+id/llBottomButtom"` line above id declaration, add it below LinearLayout so it is avail to FrameLayout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.googlemapactivity.GoogleMapMainActivity" />


<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/llBottomButtom"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="90">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnOne"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Route" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnTwo"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Current" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnThree"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Charge" />


</LinearLayout>

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frameTop"
    android:layout_above="@+id/llBottomButtom"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Comment: Once the Framelayout gets any Fragment loaded in its container , Map stops working.

Comment: can you please explain why you need frameTop FrameLayout ?

Comment: The thing is I am adding a layout to show some additional UI component on to of the map for that I am adding a layout.

Comment: it is because your FrameLayout cover the map fragment, have  tried my above code.? as you have given match_parent height to FrameLayout try wrap_content.

Comment: I Got tjhe Answer, Adding it.

Comment: Thanks for the help Dhiren

Answer (score 0):

So I did a little documentation reading of the Google Maps and saw that the Maps provided the cameraAnimation method where we can add the scroll ourself, So what I did was implemented a GestureDetector.OnGestureListener and inside that there are two methods which I used in the manner provided below

```
  override fun onFling(e1: MotionEvent?, e2: MotionEvent?, velocityX: Float, velocityY: Float): Boolean {
        googMaps?.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.scrollBy(velocityX, velocityY))
        return true
    }

    override fun onScroll(e1: MotionEvent?, e2: MotionEvent?, distanceX: Float, distanceY: Float): Boolean {
        googMaps?.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.scrollBy(distanceX, distanceY))
        return true
    }
```

This did the trick and now I can use the Custom Layout with Fragment above my map and it still scrolls and functions the same.